# How many 8 digit Natural numbers are there whose digits are from the set {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9} which are divisible by 275?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, divisibility

How many 8-digit Natural numbers are there whose digits are from the set {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9} which are divisible by 275?
275 = 5^2 * 11
There will be two cases -
One in which 25 is at the end and one in which 75 is at the end and I thought that there would be two cases of each because

a b c d e f 2 5

(b+d+f+5)-(a+c+e+2) = 0 or 11 and the same with the case of 75

Now I tried making cases but couldn't find a way to solve the question properly. Can somebody help me with this

Comment: Your instinct that $~|(a + c + e + 2) - (b + d + f + 5)| \leq 11~$ and  $~|(a + c + e + 7) - (b + d + f + 5)| \leq 11~$ is sound because $~(9 + 8 + 7 + 6) - (5 + 4 + 3 + 2) < 22.~$  **However,** MathSE protocol requires that you edit your posting to show  significant work in attempting to work through the cases.  Until this is done, MathSE protocol prevents someone from posting an answer.

Comment: Obviously, no even multiple of $275$ will fail to feature a $0$. FWIW, the smallest such number is 11111375.

Answer (score 0):

The smallest integer of eight digits does not containing zeros is $11\space111\space111$ and the largest  is $99\space999\space999$.  Since $11\space111\space111\equiv{11}\pmod{275}$  the first of our integers multiples of $275$  is $11\space111\space375$; similarly $99\space999\space999\equiv99\pmod{275}$ gives for the last one $99\space999\space625$.
We need now to calculate $h$ in$$11\space111\space375+550h=99\space999\space625\Rightarrow h=161\space615$$
so there are in total $161\space617$ integers to consider from which we must discarded those that would contain zeros.

Trying to get a pattern to localized the integers containing zeros in the Arithmetic progressions
$$11\space111\space375+550h\hspace2cm(1)\\99\space999\space625-550h\hspace2cm(2)$$  for the the values $h=1,2,3,\cdots,100$ we find $17$ integers to be excluded in $(1)$ and $18$ in $(2)$. It follows there are $165$ of the required integers plus all the analogues without zeros in
$$11\space166\space375+550h\le 99\space944\space625; \space h\ge0$$
It is complicated to get a pattern if there is one and I think there is not possible a direct calculation other than brute force. I am maybe wrong about this.

Comment: The question is only interested in multiples that do not contain the digit $0$ anywhere in their base ten representation.

Comment: @Daniel Mathias Right! it remains an aditional detail to finish and probably  there are zeros in the considered sucessive multiples. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Mathematica to verify your result.

#### DO NOT admit repeat digits

```
(*Generate the list of 8-digit numbers divisible by 275*)
numbers = Range[Ceiling[10000000/275]*275, Floor[99999999/275]*275, 275];

(*Filter out numbers with 0 or repeated digits*)
validNumbers = 
  Select[numbers, 
   FreeQ[IntegerDigits[#], 0] && DuplicateFreeQ[IntegerDigits[#]] &];

(*Get the count*)
Length[validNumbers]
```

$$
\color{red}{972}
$$

#### admit repeat digits

```
(*Generate the list of 8-digit numbers divisible by 275*)
numbers = Range[Ceiling[10000000/275]*275, Floor[99999999/275]*275, 275];

(*Filter out numbers with 0 or repeated digits*)
validNumbers = Select[numbers, FreeQ[IntegerDigits[#], 0] &];

(*Get the count*)
Length[validNumbers]
```

$$
\color{red}{96621}
$$